# Change int from xml Resource

Tags: android, android-resources

I am new in Android Studio and i like the idea of having a resources files so I open a resource file (xml) in the name of integers and i put this code in him:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="omry">1</integer>
</resources>
```

and my code that get the var is:

```
Integer zomry101 = new Integer(this.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.omry));
```

and now i want do that if i click on a button it will add 1 to the omry int in the file, I know how to do the click event but  I dont know how to change the xml file.
please help.

Comment: resource files cannot be changed at runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing's first **Resources CAN NOT be Changed or Modified** once an apk has been built. You can only add values to resources that need not to be modified.

So what to do? [Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html) allow you to save and modify values at run time. This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values?answertab=active#tab-top) explains how to use `Shared Preferences` in your app.

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/esripdx/Android-Static-Utils/blob/master/src/com/esri/android/util/SharedPrefsUtils.java) for easy to use `Utility` for `Shared Preferences`.

Comment: Thank you very much!
i will try this

Answer (score 0):

The res folder cannot be changed at runtime.